# How do I solve this error message regarding rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run a rails s command in the terminal,but I keep receiving a trace back: of multiple errors.

I tried have multiple ways to solve this issue but to no avail not has granted me with a solution.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from ./bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    3: from ./bin/rails:3:in `load'
    2: from /home/zac/code2/rails-mister-cocktail/bin/spring:8:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /home/zac/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/home/zac/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
```

I expected the server to run without any issues.

Comment: Have you installed the Bundler gem? `gem install bundler` It can’t find it to require it, which leads me to believe you haven’t installed it.

Comment: I was given another error message: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
 format version 4.8 required; 60.33 given
This what I got when I tried using "gem install bundler"

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error. If you have versions of ruby, **bundler** or rails installed on your machine that are different than the ones being used in the rails app you're trying to run, then installing the matching versions can make it work. Check the bundler version that was used on the app so you can run in the terminal:

`gem install bundler -v '~> 1.17.3'` (replace 1.17.3 with the version being used)

Also check the ruby and rails versions you have match the versions described in the Gemfile. You can check the versions you have installed with `ruby -v` and `rails -v`